# SQL сравнение двух таблиц по двум колонкам

Tags: sql, postgresql

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Используется PostgreSql.

Необходимо сделать `SELECT`, который выведет строку из таблицы 1, которой нет во второй таблице `(t1.sip  = t2.sip, t2.name содержит t1.mac)`.

То есть результат должен быть:

> user1 | bbbbbbbbbbbb

---

Я пробовал сделать так:

```
SELECT t1.sip, t1.mac FROM t1 LEFT JOIN regs ON t1.sip=t2.sip where t2.sip IS NULL;
```

Не прошел так как `user1` есть в обоих таблицах, нужна была доп. проверка, содержит ли `t2.name` `t1.mac`.

---

Поэтому я попробовал следующее: 
`SELECT DISTINCT( t1.sip), t1.mac FROM t1 LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.sip=t2.sip t2.ua NOT  LIKE CONCAT('%',wa.mac,'%');`

Результат получился:

> user1 | bbbbbbbbbbbb

---

Но если в `t2` всё таки появится запись

> user1 | test(bbbbbbbbbbbb)

, тогда результатом будет:

> user1 | bbbbbbbbbbbb
>
> user1 | aaaaaaaaaaaa

Но мне надо, чтобы в результате не было этих строк, так как они подходят под условия

```
t1.sip  = t2.sip, t2.name содержит t1.mac
```

Comment: left join+ where is null

Comment: left join+ where is null
Не подходит. По крайней мере у меня не получилось. 
Сложность в том что user1 и bbbbbbbbbbbb как бы содержаться в таблице 2, а вот их связка нет. Я не знаю как правильно написать,  то что мне нужно.

Comment: @Akina `not exists` лучше

Comment: @SergeyRakov в left join в on можно написать все требуемые условия `on a.sip=b.sip and a.mac=b.mac` ну с b.mac конечно надо немного substr повозиться что бы выделить только mac из него

Comment: SELECT t1.* FROM TABLE1 t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE2 t2 ON t2.SIP = t1.SIP
WHERE t1.MAC ~* substring(t2.MAC from 5 for 14);

Answer (score 0):

Вот такой запрос мне был необходим:

```
SELECT DISTINCT( t1.sip), t1.mac FROM t1 LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.sip = t2.sip 
and t2.name LIKE CONCAT ('%',t1.mac,'%') WHERE t2 IS NULL;
```

Comment: а это нормально, что у Вас TABLE1.SIP не уникальнное значения